# Using multiple Bundler versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I've joined a project which is using bundler version 1.17.1 . Currently my system is using bundler 2.0.2 . Is there any way for me to specify a bundler version just like specifying ruby version with `rbenv`. Something likes:

```
bundler --global 1.17.1
```

So that, when I run the command `bundler -v` I will receive the result `1.71.1` rather than `2.0.2`

I tried to uninstall the current bundler with `gem uninstall bundler` and received this message:

```
$ gem uninstall bundler

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. bundler-1.17.1
 2. bundler-1.17.3
 3. bundler-2.0.2
 4. All versions
>
```

That makes me think there is a certain way allows me to work with multiple bundler versions. Any clues just for pointing me to where I should look up would be really appreciated.

### EDIT 1

I tried `bundle _1.17.1_ --version` and it didn't work as I expected

```
$ bundler -v
Bundler version 2.0.2
$ bundle _1.17.1_ --version
Bundler version 1.17.1
$ bundler -v
Bundler version 2.0.2
```

**expected:** Bundler version 1.17.1

**actual:** Bundler version 2.0.2

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Try this:**

**1)** `gem install bundler -v 1.17.1`

**2)** `bundle _1.17.1_ install`

Comment: Accepted! Looks like this is the only way: `bundle _1.17.1_ install`

Comment: @NguyenYou It's nice that it helped :)

Comment: It doesn't work for me: `> file ~/.gems/gems/bundler-1.17.1` outputs `/Users/iulian/.gems/gems/bundler-1.17.1: directory` and `> bundle _1.17.1_ --version` outputs `Bundler version 2.0.2`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with version two alike: `bundle _2.*.*_ install`.

Comment: @angerhang Have you tried ``bundle update --bundler`` ?

Comment: when I try to run ```bundle _1.3.0_ install``` on my machine, Im always getting Could not find command "_1.3.0_"

Comment: while using `bundle exec` which version will it use?

Answer (score 6):

You can specify multiple bundler versions by using underscores: RubyGems already provides this functionality. Specify the version number in underscores as the first argument on the command line.

```
$ bundle _1.1.3_ --version
Bundler version 1.1.3
$ bundle _1.1.0_ --version
Bundler version 1.1.0
$ bundle _1.0.22_ --version
Bundler version 1.0.22
```

There's an issue in rbenv with a similar question: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/235.

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't change the default. You need to add the version `_1.17.1_` every time you run the `bundle` command. Or if you want `bundle` command to point to this version every time, you can alias it in your rc file like `alias bundle='bundle _1.17.1_'`.

Comment: ```bundle _1.3.0_ install``` returns ```Could not find command "_1.3.0_".```